# How do you get the mean and std of a column in a csr_matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse 988x1 vector (a column in a `csr_matrix`) created through `scipy.sparse`. Is there a way to gets its mean and standard deviation without having to convert the sparse matrix to a dense one?

`numpy.mean` seems to only work for dense vectors.

Comment: [Sum the entries](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sum.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sum) and divide by m*n to calculate the mean. Assuming that's what the mean is for a matrix. I've never come across matrix mean before.

Comment: Hi David, I should have edited my question, I'm looking for finding the mean and std of a vector rather, but in its sparse form, is there a command in scipy that gets you those two values?

Comment: So, is my definition in the comment accurate? It's the sum of the 988 values, divided by 988? And why are you using CSR if you work with columns?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, because I am extracting TFIDF as a feature vector for each document that I have in the corpus, which tends to be sparse and very large: the csr_matrix is around 988x40,000 in dimensions. You are correct about the procedure in calculating the mean, but even numpy.sum does not work with sparse vectors, I have to do nested loops to achieve this, but I would rather avoid such loops! Moreover, I'm working with columns to find which features are most correlated with the target, and this is done by applying the correlation function between each column to the target.

Comment: It would be faster to use csc when working with columns. You can use the sum function that I linked to in my first comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks mate, its working perfectly! I agree with you on using csc :). Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are performing column slicing, it may be better to store the matrix using CSC rather than CSR. But that would depend on what else you are doing with the matrix.

To calculate the mean of a column in a CSC matrix you can use the [`mean()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.mean.html#scipy-sparse-csc-matrix-mean) function of the matrix.

To calculate the standard deviation efficiently is going to involve just a bit more effort. First of all, suppose you get your sparse column like this:

```
col = A.getcol(colindex)
```

Then calculate the variance like so:

```
N = col.shape[0]
sqr = col.copy() # take a copy of the col
sqr.data **= 2 # square the data, i.e. just the non-zero data
variance = sqr.sum()/N - col.mean()**2
```

Comment: +1. An alternative approach (shameless plug for my own project) is to use the [`StandardScaler` from scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), which has an optimized mean+variance computation for CSR and CSC matrices.

Comment: @larsmans I get `"Cannot center sparse matrices: pass 'with_mean=False' "` with csr_matrix.